# Bootstrap table data localized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

How to localize data in bootstrap table? 
Example, I have list of statuses in asp.net resource file with different languages. When switch language, the status text will change based on the language code. But, how to apply this to data in bootstrap table? Pls bear if I using wrong terms.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can update data in bootstrap table

destroy the table,

```
$('#tableId').bootstrapTable("destroy");
```

and then reload the data,

```
$('#tableId').bootstrapTable({data: myFreshData});
```